# DVI-D single link / DVI-D dual link

Tags: dvi, playstation

Can I put my DVI-D single link in my computer, wich has a DCI-D dual link input?

I bought a DVI-D to HDMI cable to connect my PC screen to the playstation. Unfortunately I bought a DVI-D single link, and the computer I'm going to connect it to has a DVI-D dual link input. I haven't opened the package yet, and I don't know if I should open it and try, or return it (and get a refund) and then buy the correct one?

Comment: You should return it.

Answer (score 0):

Physically, it will plug in - the single link connector has less pins than the dual link connector.

You could probably even use it - with certain restrictions - Less bandwidth and lower resolutions supported (1920 × 1200 @ 60hz is the maximum supported over single link.  Dual-link takes this up to 2560 × 1600 @ 60 Hz).

As you have not opened the package, you should return/replace the cable and get the correct one.